# Is the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ uniformly continuous on the interval $(0.2 ,1)$?

Tags: uniform-continuity

Is the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ uniformly continuous on the interval $(0.2, 1)$?

edit1:
I know from my textbook and other posts that the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is not uniformly continuous on intervals such as $(0,1]$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: It’s uniformly continuous on the closure of that interval

Comment: Try $\delta>5\epsilon$

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [Heine-Cantor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem), it is uniformly continuous on each bounded and closed interval not containing $0$.

Moreover, obviously, if it is continuous on $[0.2, 1]$, it is uniformly continuous on each interval contained in it.

Comment: Sorry for asking too simple a question. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1